# Dictionary __new__ call issue with unpickled argument

Tags: python, class, dictionary, pickle

So I tried to create a subclass of `dict` to make it 1) immutable and 2) accept pickled data, but when it is supposed to unpickle the data, it fails with the error: `TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence`

Here is my code:

```
>>> class Message(dict):   
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            """Create a new message object."""
            if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], bytes):
                args = (pickle.loads(args[0]),)
            return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

>>> Message({"a": 1})
{'a': 1}
>>> Message(pickle.dumps({"a": 1}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#99>", line 1, in <module>
    Message(pickle.dumps({"a": 1}))
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

**EDIT**

I changed it to:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    """Create a new message object."""
    if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], bytes):
        args = (pickle.loads(args[0]),)
    self = super().__new__(cls)
    self.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return self
```

But it still doesn't work, so the `__new__` -> `__init__` didn't help either.

Comment: so... you want that `Message(pickle.dumps({"a": 1})) == Message({"a": 1})` should hold?  That's a bit strange... what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just want to make it faster to load incoming messages from the server (this is for a chat service). It's not necessary, but I now want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: as Eevee points out in comments, you must *override* `__init__`.  to then get data in your dict, use `super().update(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because `dict.__new__` doesn't do what you think it does;  It always returns a new, empty dict.

The arguments are then passed to `dict.__init__`, which will update `self` (our dict subclass) according to its parameters.

So, alas, you can't do `dict(pickle.dumps({'a':1})`.

As a workaround, you could call `super().update()` in `__new__`, and provide a do-nothing `__init__`, but I would not do that.  Maybe what you really want is plain-ol `pickle.loads(...)` instead of `MyFancySubclass(pickle.loads(...))`;

***EDIT*** since it's apparently not clear, your subclass must look like this:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass # DO NOTHING!

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self.update(get_some_data(args, kwargs))  # NOT __init__
        return self
```

Comment: don't call `__init__` within `__new__`.  (ever!)  `__init__` is automatically called _after_ `__new__`.  you have to override it.